# how to get mango db lost host connect string

Tags: postman, kohana-mangodb

I want to create one app so want to local host Mongodb string for connecting database

almost connect the local host but in potman  give a error for request but  error in postman because of not connect the string properly so how to connect local host

Comment: Hi, what errors do you get? What connection string are you using? Without details it's very hard for us to help